# How to setup async in series for nested functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have two async functions that need to run in series.

FunctionA needs to be completed in all nested functions  before FunctionB is run.

Nested functions pass a variable to the next function.

Functions first*A2 and second*B2 do not return a value.

Is there a way accomplish it without using timeout?

```
FunctionA()
FunctionB()



FunctionA: function (){
---
----
first_A1(X)
}

first_A1:function(X){
----
----
first_A2(Y)}
}

first_A2(Y){
-----
-----
}

FunctionB: function (){
---
----
second_B1(Z)
}

second_B1:function(Z){
----
----
second_B2(G)}
}

second_B2(G){
-----
-----
}
```

Comment: Since you've tagged this question with [tag:javascript], could you please [edit] it to contain actual valid JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic async/await. You can learn more on MDN or any other JavaScript documentation of your choice. Of course, you can do it with Promises as well, but I personally prefer async/await syntax (it's much more simple and readable for my taste).

Anyway, if I understood correctly what you are trying to accomplish, here's how to do it:

```
async function functionA() {
  let result = await firstA1();
  // since your requirements mentioned that "nested functions are passing variable to next functions", I've assumed that you wanted to process the result somehow. You can really, pass anything to firstA2 here
  await firstA2(result);
  // since your example lists two calls, here's the second call
  await firstA2(result);
  return result;
}

// Same goes for function B and its "nested" functions
async function functionB() {
  let result = await secondB1();
  await secondB2(result);
  await secondB2(result);
  return result;
}

// Now to run both in series... functionB will not be run until functionA and all its nested functions completes.
async function runFunctionsInSeries() {
  let resultA = await functionA();
  let resultB = await functionB();
}
```

**Edit based on the feedback from OP**
If you want to use the results from previous functions in the next ones, simply change the above code to this (code adapted to demonstrate OP's X, Y,... variables):

```
async function functionA() {
  let X = await firstA1();
  let Y = await firstA2(X);
  let result = await firstA2(Y);
  return result;
}

async function functionB() {
  let X = await secondB1();
  let Y = await secondB2(X);
  let result = secondB2(Y);
  return result;
}

async function runFunctionsInSeries() {
  let resultA = await functionA();
  let resultB = await functionB();
}
```

Please note that I have used `let` instead of `const` statements here, in case you need to some more processing and change the contents of variables in your functions.

The `await` keyword, when put if front of an `async` function call will wait for the Promise to be resolved before allowing your application to run the next line of code.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: THe variable that is produced in the Function A, namely X, is passed on to the function first_A1. Then, another variable is produced, Y, which is passed on to first_A2. At last in first_A2, it displays the final result of calculations involving Y.  When the first_A2 finishes its execution, then Function B should start executing in the similar fashion. In my example there are no returns. That's my issue to execute the nested functions in series with no return values.

Comment: @LefterisKoumis I have updated the answer to reflect your comment. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

See [promise concurrency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#promise_concurrency) for various ways to achieve what you are after.

> Promise.all() Fulfills when all of the promises fulfill; rejects when
> any of the promises rejects.
>
> Promise.allSettled() Fulfills when all promises settle.
>
> Promise.any() Fulfills when any of the promises fulfills; rejects when
> all of the promises reject.
>
> Promise.race() Settles when any of the promises settles. In other
> words, fulfills when any of the promises fulfills; rejects when any of
> the promises rejects.